# Maximum number of databases supported by MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create a database for each customer. But before, I would like to know how many  databases can be created in a single instance of MongoDB ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> There's no explicit limit, but there are probably some implicit limits
>   due to max number of open file handles / files in a directory on the
>   host OS/filesystem.

see: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/01727e1af681985a?fwc=2

Answer (score -6):

By default, you can run some 12,000 collections in  a single instance of MongoDB( that is, if each collection also has 1 index).

If you want to create more number of collections, then use --nssize when you run mongod process. You can see this link for more details:

**http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections**

Comment: Collections are not the same as databases. All collections within a database are stored within the same set of database files. Each database has a separate set of files (including its .ns namespace file). Specifying a larger --nssize means that *each* database can support more collections. This does not answer how many databases MongoDB supports.

Comment: Thats true.  We can have any number of collections in a database. Collection in Mongodb is analogous to a table and not a database.