# How many db can I create within a MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, backend

I would like to create a backend with MongoDB to handle my data.

For each of my user (a user represent a company) I would like to create a new db to keep all the data separated from the other companies. All of these dbs will have the same structure to be plugged into a client software.

Is it possible to do it? Is it the right way to do it?
If it is possible with mongoDB, is there a limit of the number of dbs that can be created ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum number of databases supported by MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922806/maximum-number-of-databases-supported-by-mongodb) I would say that's not the right way to do, you can keep everything in one db in one collection as docs are isolated to each other, or at least in multiple collections(that too not recommended)..

Comment: Yes it answer my question, thx. But, a user will have thousands of records, if all the data are in the same collection, how can a user restore a backup (for example) without 'touching' other company data? I'm used to SQL and I'm not confortable with MondoDB yet

Comment: that case try creating multiple collections in a DB rather than DB's itself..

Comment: Ok I'm going to think about it.

Comment: If you have to separate your data in such way, then you may consider also [directoryPerDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#storage.directoryPerDB)

Comment: MongoDB stores data as [databases and collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/). A collection has [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/). _May be_ it is that the user / company is to be a collection of documents where each _user_ is represented by a document. Also, see [FAQs: MongoDB fundamentals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/index.html).